# How to use CoinMarketCap API in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, coinmarketcap

I'm following a tutorial for an app that displays cryptocurrency prices and I have trouble with the new API. The code below is just from the tutorial and the tutor is using the old coinmarketcap API. Coinmarketcap has migrated to a new one and you need to sign up to get a free API key. Documentation for new API: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1.

I think I need to change _apiURL to https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD and somehow use the APIKey. Does anyone have a solution? Still kinda new to flutter and API's so i'm sorry if the question is hard to answer.

```
Future<void> getCryptoPrices() async {
//async to use await, which suspends the current function, while it does other stuff and resumes when data ready
print('getting crypto prices'); //print
String _apiURL =
    "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"; //url to get data
setState(() {
  this._loading = true; //before calling the api, set the loading to true
});
http.Response response = await http.get(_apiURL); //waits for response
setState(() {
  this._cryptoList =
      jsonDecode(response.body); //sets the state of our widget
  this._loading = false; //set the loading to false after we get a response
  print(_cryptoList); //prints the list
});
return;  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below and replace `your-key` before run 
You can put `API key` in `headers` and parse json response with `payloadFromJson` and display with `FutureBuilder` 
You can see Payload class definition in full code

```
Future<Payload> getCryptoPrices() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD",
        headers: {
          'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'your-key',
          "Accept": "application/json",
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return payloadFromJson(response.body);
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  Payload({
    this.status,
    this.data,
  });

  Status status;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        status: Status.fromJson(json["status"]),
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status.toJson(),
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.symbol,
    this.slug,
    this.numMarketPairs,
    this.dateAdded,
    this.tags,
    this.maxSupply,
    this.circulatingSupply,
    this.totalSupply,
    this.platform,
    this.cmcRank,
    this.lastUpdated,
    this.quote,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String symbol;
  String slug;
  int numMarketPairs;
  DateTime dateAdded;
  List<Tag> tags;
  double maxSupply;
  double circulatingSupply;
  double totalSupply;
  Platform platform;
  int cmcRank;
  DateTime lastUpdated;
  Quote quote;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        symbol: json["symbol"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        numMarketPairs: json["num_market_pairs"],
        dateAdded: DateTime.parse(json["date_added"]),
        tags: List<Tag>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => tagValues.map[x])),
        maxSupply:
            json["max_supply"] == null ? null : json["max_supply"].toDouble(),
        circulatingSupply: json["circulating_supply"] == null
            ? null
            : json["circulating_supply"].toDouble(),
        totalSupply: json["total_supply"] == null
            ? null
            : json["total_supply"].toDouble(),
        platform: json["platform"] == null
            ? null
            : Platform.fromJson(json["platform"]),
        cmcRank: json["cmc_rank"],
        lastUpdated: DateTime.parse(json["last_updated"]),
        quote: Quote.fromJson(json["quote"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "slug": slug,
        "num_market_pairs": numMarketPairs,
        "date_added": dateAdded.toIso8601String(),
        "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => tagValues.reverse[x])),
        "max_supply": maxSupply == null ? null : maxSupply,
        "circulating_supply":
            circulatingSupply == null ? null : circulatingSupply,
        "total_supply": totalSupply == null ? null : totalSupply,
        "platform": platform == null ? null : platform.toJson(),
        "cmc_rank": cmcRank,
        "last_updated": lastUpdated.toIso8601String(),
        "quote": quote.toJson(),
      };
}

class Platform {
  Platform({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.symbol,
    this.slug,
    this.tokenAddress,
  });

  int id;
  Name name;
  Symbol symbol;
  Slug slug;
  String tokenAddress;

  factory Platform.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Platform(
        id: json["id"],
        name: nameValues.map[json["name"]],
        symbol: symbolValues.map[json["symbol"]],
        slug: slugValues.map[json["slug"]],
        tokenAddress: json["token_address"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": nameValues.reverse[name],
        "symbol": symbolValues.reverse[symbol],
        "slug": slugValues.reverse[slug],
        "token_address": tokenAddress,
      };
}

enum Name {
  ETHEREUM,
  TRON,
  OMNI,
  RSK_SMART_BITCOIN,
  BINANCE_COIN,
  STELLAR,
  NEO,
  V_SYSTEMS,
  ARDOR,
  QTUM,
  XRP,
  WAVES,
  ONTOLOGY,
  EOS,
  NEBULAS,
  NEM,
  BIT_SHARES,
  BITCOIN_CASH,
  INT_CHAIN,
  COSMOS,
  UBIQ,
  VE_CHAIN,
  NU_BITS,
  PIVX,
  COUNTERPARTY,
  KOMODO,
  ICON,
  GX_CHAIN,
  VITE,
  WANCHAIN,
  IOST,
  TRUE_CHAIN,
  ETHEREUM_CLASSIC
}

final nameValues = EnumValues({
  "Ardor": Name.ARDOR,
  "Binance Coin": Name.BINANCE_COIN,
  "Bitcoin Cash": Name.BITCOIN_CASH,
  "BitShares": Name.BIT_SHARES,
  "Cosmos": Name.COSMOS,
  "Counterparty": Name.COUNTERPARTY,
  "EOS": Name.EOS,
  "Ethereum": Name.ETHEREUM,
  "Ethereum Classic": Name.ETHEREUM_CLASSIC,
  "GXChain": Name.GX_CHAIN,
  "ICON": Name.ICON,
  "INT Chain": Name.INT_CHAIN,
  "IOST": Name.IOST,
  "Komodo": Name.KOMODO,
  "Nebulas": Name.NEBULAS,
  "NEM": Name.NEM,
  "Neo": Name.NEO,
  "NuBits": Name.NU_BITS,
  "Omni": Name.OMNI,
  "Ontology": Name.ONTOLOGY,
  "PIVX": Name.PIVX,
  "Qtum": Name.QTUM,
  "RSK Smart Bitcoin": Name.RSK_SMART_BITCOIN,
  "Stellar": Name.STELLAR,
  "TRON": Name.TRON,
  "TrueChain": Name.TRUE_CHAIN,
  "Ubiq": Name.UBIQ,
  "VeChain": Name.VE_CHAIN,
  "VITE": Name.VITE,
  "v.systems": Name.V_SYSTEMS,
  "Wanchain": Name.WANCHAIN,
  "Waves": Name.WAVES,
  "XRP": Name.XRP
});

enum Slug {
  ETHEREUM,
  TRON,
  OMNI,
  RSK_SMART_BITCOIN,
  BINANCE_COIN,
  STELLAR,
  NEO,
  V_SYSTEMS,
  ARDOR,
  QTUM,
  XRP,
  WAVES,
  ONTOLOGY,
  EOS,
  NEBULAS_TOKEN,
  NEM,
  BITSHARES,
  BITCOIN_CASH,
  INT_CHAIN,
  COSMOS,
  UBIQ,
  VECHAIN,
  NUBITS,
  PIVX,
  COUNTERPARTY,
  KOMODO,
  ICON,
  GXCHAIN,
  VITE,
  WANCHAIN,
  IOSTOKEN,
  TRUECHAIN,
  ETHEREUM_CLASSIC
}

final slugValues = EnumValues({
  "ardor": Slug.ARDOR,
  "binance-coin": Slug.BINANCE_COIN,
  "bitcoin-cash": Slug.BITCOIN_CASH,
  "bitshares": Slug.BITSHARES,
  "cosmos": Slug.COSMOS,
  "counterparty": Slug.COUNTERPARTY,
  "eos": Slug.EOS,
  "ethereum": Slug.ETHEREUM,
  "ethereum-classic": Slug.ETHEREUM_CLASSIC,
  "gxchain": Slug.GXCHAIN,
  "icon": Slug.ICON,
  "int-chain": Slug.INT_CHAIN,
  "iostoken": Slug.IOSTOKEN,
  "komodo": Slug.KOMODO,
  "nebulas-token": Slug.NEBULAS_TOKEN,
  "nem": Slug.NEM,
  "neo": Slug.NEO,
  "nubits": Slug.NUBITS,
  "omni": Slug.OMNI,
  "ontology": Slug.ONTOLOGY,
  "pivx": Slug.PIVX,
  "qtum": Slug.QTUM,
  "rsk-smart-bitcoin": Slug.RSK_SMART_BITCOIN,
  "stellar": Slug.STELLAR,
  "tron": Slug.TRON,
  "truechain": Slug.TRUECHAIN,
  "ubiq": Slug.UBIQ,
  "vechain": Slug.VECHAIN,
  "vite": Slug.VITE,
  "v-systems": Slug.V_SYSTEMS,
  "wanchain": Slug.WANCHAIN,
  "waves": Slug.WAVES,
  "xrp": Slug.XRP
});

enum Symbol {
  ETH,
  TRX,
  OMNI,
  RBTC,
  BNB,
  XLM,
  NEO,
  VSYS,
  ARDR,
  QTUM,
  XRP,
  WAVES,
  ONT,
  EOS,
  NAS,
  XEM,
  BTS,
  BCH,
  INT,
  ATOM,
  UBQ,
  VET,
  USNBT,
  PIVX,
  XCP,
  KMD,
  ICX,
  GXC,
  VITE,
  WAN,
  IOST,
  TRUE,
  ETC
}

final symbolValues = EnumValues({
  "ARDR": Symbol.ARDR,
  "ATOM": Symbol.ATOM,
  "BCH": Symbol.BCH,
  "BNB": Symbol.BNB,
  "BTS": Symbol.BTS,
  "EOS": Symbol.EOS,
  "ETC": Symbol.ETC,
  "ETH": Symbol.ETH,
  "GXC": Symbol.GXC,
  "ICX": Symbol.ICX,
  "INT": Symbol.INT,
  "IOST": Symbol.IOST,
  "KMD": Symbol.KMD,
  "NAS": Symbol.NAS,
  "NEO": Symbol.NEO,
  "OMNI": Symbol.OMNI,
  "ONT": Symbol.ONT,
  "PIVX": Symbol.PIVX,
  "QTUM": Symbol.QTUM,
  "RBTC": Symbol.RBTC,
  "TRUE": Symbol.TRUE,
  "TRX": Symbol.TRX,
  "UBQ": Symbol.UBQ,
  "USNBT": Symbol.USNBT,
  "VET": Symbol.VET,
  "VITE": Symbol.VITE,
  "VSYS": Symbol.VSYS,
  "WAN": Symbol.WAN,
  "WAVES": Symbol.WAVES,
  "XCP": Symbol.XCP,
  "XEM": Symbol.XEM,
  "XLM": Symbol.XLM,
  "XRP": Symbol.XRP
});

class Quote {
  Quote({
    this.usd,
  });

  Usd usd;

  factory Quote.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Quote(
        usd: Usd.fromJson(json["USD"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "USD": usd.toJson(),
      };
}

class Usd {
  Usd({
    this.price,
    this.volume24H,
    this.percentChange1H,
    this.percentChange24H,
    this.percentChange7D,
    this.marketCap,
    this.lastUpdated,
  });

  double price;
  double volume24H;
  double percentChange1H;
  double percentChange24H;
  double percentChange7D;
  double marketCap;
  DateTime lastUpdated;

  factory Usd.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Usd(
        price: json["price"] == null ? null : json["price"].toDouble(),
        volume24H:
            json["volume_24h"] == null ? null : json["volume_24h"].toDouble(),
        percentChange1H: json["percent_change_1h"] == null
            ? null
            : json["percent_change_1h"].toDouble(),
        percentChange24H: json["percent_change_24h"] == null
            ? null
            : json["percent_change_24h"].toDouble(),
        percentChange7D: json["percent_change_7d"] == null
            ? null
            : json["percent_change_7d"].toDouble(),
        marketCap:
            json["market_cap"] == null ? null : json["market_cap"].toDouble(),
        lastUpdated: DateTime.parse(json["last_updated"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "price": price == null ? null : price,
        "volume_24h": volume24H == null ? null : volume24H,
        "percent_change_1h": percentChange1H == null ? null : percentChange1H,
        "percent_change_24h":
            percentChange24H == null ? null : percentChange24H,
        "percent_change_7d": percentChange7D == null ? null : percentChange7D,
        "market_cap": marketCap == null ? null : marketCap,
        "last_updated": lastUpdated.toIso8601String(),
      };
}

enum Tag { MINEABLE }

final tagValues = EnumValues({"mineable": Tag.MINEABLE});

class Status {
  Status({
    this.timestamp,
    this.errorCode,
    this.errorMessage,
    this.elapsed,
    this.creditCount,
    this.notice,
  });

  DateTime timestamp;
  int errorCode;
  dynamic errorMessage;
  int elapsed;
  int creditCount;
  dynamic notice;

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Status(
        timestamp: DateTime.parse(json["timestamp"]),
        errorCode: json["error_code"],
        errorMessage: json["error_message"],
        elapsed: json["elapsed"],
        creditCount: json["credit_count"],
        notice: json["notice"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "timestamp": timestamp.toIso8601String(),
        "error_code": errorCode,
        "error_message": errorMessage,
        "elapsed": elapsed,
        "credit_count": creditCount,
        "notice": notice,
      };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Future<Payload> _future;

  Future<Payload> getCryptoPrices() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD",
        headers: {
          'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'your-key',
          "Accept": "application/json",
        });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return payloadFromJson(response.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _future = getCryptoPrices();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Payload> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(snapshot.data.data[index].name),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(snapshot.data.data[index].lastUpdated
                                        .toIso8601String()),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data.data[index].quote.usd.price
                                          .toString(),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it hard to get the logos aswell from the API?

Comment: I did not see logo field name in API response. Is it a png or jpeg.

Comment: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyInfo. PNG under "logo".